# Power supply for (30km stratosphere) school's High Altitude Balloon project

Tags: balloons

Our local amateur radio club has been approached by Veikkola junior school with regard to our members participating in the school's proposed High altitude balloon project (Spring 2017); in particular with reference to realizing position reporting (APRS) and possible live stream video imaging.

Given that the target altitude will be approx. 30km, temp -40C(?) and payload capacity 1000g, what sort of power supply should we contemplate, together with any necessary means to keep it warmed?

Comment: How long is the flight? Batteries may do.

Comment: This might be better posed on [aviation.se] than here, because 30 km altitude is still solidly within the atmosphere and far below the edge of space (commonly defined as the Kármán line at 100 km). You can "flag" your question for moderator attention and request migration if you want to.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling We do have precedent for questions of this altitude where it relates to Space Exploration: http://space.stackexchange.com/questions/12200/scientifically-useful-measurements-from-low-budget-high-altitude-balloon-flights. I suggest the OP edit to clarify any connection to Space Exploration. If there is none, I will migrate.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling Another example of this altitude: http://space.stackexchange.com/questions/2213/what-are-the-risks-involved-in-amateur-high-altitude-ballooning-and-how-can-we

Comment: @called2voyage I did recall having seen some, which is why I didn't vote to close outright but rather tried to make it clear to the OP that flagging for moderator attention and requesting migration was a suggestion.

Comment: If there is any thought to have a GPS as part of the payload, remember to double check that a model is chosen that is known to be "high altitude balloon-friendly". Some units will stop reporting positions above 60,000 feet. You can search this stackexchange site as well as others for more info.

Answer (score 6):

"Primary" (non-rechargeable) lithium AA batteries are the popular choice for amateur high altitude balloon projects.

Not too expensive, good energy density and they hold up well under low temperature compared to most other kinds of cell (notably rechargeable Li-Ion or LiPo are not good in the cold).

Be aware that depending on how you insulate your "payload compartment" and how much power is being dissipated inside it, the interior may actually end up quite warm due to the low air density and correspondingly reduced convective cooling.