# What do astronauts do to pass time on the way to the ISS?

Tags: astronauts, astronaut-lifestyle

After watching those astronauts wait in the dragon capsule for so long on Tuesday, I started to wonder what do they do on the long trip to the space station? Can they get out of their seats? Are there movies to watch?

Comment: Anecdote and speculation: On any flight, there is always lots to do in terms of movement of cargo to stage it for later operations, inspections after launch, etc. In test flights such as SpaceX DM-2, there are many activities planned for evaluating the spacecraft's performance, ergonomics, procedures, etc.

Comment: related: [When astronauts travel to the ISS, how do they not get bored?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/18155/12102)