# Spacecraft Inertial Data

Tags: spacecraft, attitude, trajectory, attitude-determination-and-control

I am a developer of motion analytics algorithms. I have been using a 9 Dof strap-down IMU on human and land vehicles for these algorithms.

I Would be interested to test my algorithms with IMU data from a spacecraft. Any idea how to get hold such real data, e.g. Voyager?

Comment: If you look at the links in the question [Why are the ISS attitude values shown on these two web sites so different?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/20358/12102) and the answers there, you may find something of interest.

Comment: Glancing at the links uhoh sent--the attitude rates there look like they're probably ISSACS wrt LVLH.  The inertial rate would include the LVLH wrt ECI (e.g. J2000) rate, which will be roughly 360 degrees / the orbital rate of the station.

Comment: I would be interested in finding this as well. But I doubt such data would be available. Most likely you would need data recorded at full sampling rate, which many spacecraft don't down link with their telemetry, simply because it is too much data. Also, if you do find data, there are big chances of it being interpolated or some kind of filtered estimates, depending on your application, this would render most of these algorithms useless. Additionally, in many missions there are several limitations on which data can be published.